# Remove duplicate words in a string using regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm working on my regex skills and i find one of my strings having duplicate words at the starting. I would like to remove the duplicate and just have one word of it -

```
server_server_dev1_check_1233.zzz
server_server_qa1_run_1233.xyz
server_server_dev2_1233.qqa
server_dev1_1233.zzz
data_data_dev9_check_660.log
```

I used the below regex but i get both server_server in my output,

```
((.*?))_(?!\D)
```

How can i have my output just to one `server_` if there are two or more and if its only one `server_`, then take as is?
The output doesn't have to contain the `digits` and also the part after `.` i.e. `.zzz, .xyz` etc

Expected output -

```
server_dev1_check
server_qa1_run
server_dev2
server_dev1
data_dev9_check
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a single `re.sub` call to match and remove what you do not need and match and capture what you need:

```
re.sub(r'^([^_]+)(?:_\1)*(.*)_\d+\.\w+$', r'\1\2', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5UL4D8/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `([^_]+)` - Capturing group 1: any 1+ chars other than `_`
- `(?:_\1)*` - zero or more repetitions of `_` followed with the same substring as in Group 1 (thanks to the *inline backreference* `\1` that retrieves the text from Group 1)
- `(.*)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars, as many as possible
- `_` - an underscore
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars (`[^.]+` will also do, 1 or more chars other than `.`)
- `$` - end of string.

The replacement pattern is `\1\2`, i.e. the contents of Group 1 and 2 are concatenated and make up the resulting value.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/EzBZCB):

```
import re
rx = r'^([^_]+)(?:_\1)*(.*)_\d+\.\w+$'
strs = ["server_server_dev1_check_1233.zzz", "server_server_qa1_run_1233.xyz", "server_server_dev2_1233.qqa", "server_dev1_1233.zzz", "data_data_dev9_check_660.log"]
for s in strs:
    print(re.sub(rx, r'\1\2', s))
```

Output:

```
server_dev1_check
server_qa1_run
server_dev2
server_dev1
data_dev9_check
```

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew - thank you so much. exactly what i needed. and thanks for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 4):

you could back reference the word in your search expression:

```
>>> s = "server_server_dev1_check_1233.zzz"
>>> re.sub(r"(.*_)\1",r"\1",s)
'server_dev1_check_1233.zzz'
```

and use the "many times" suffix so if there are more than 2 occurrences it still works:

```
'server_server_server_dev1_check_1233.zzz'
>>> re.sub(r"(.*_)\1{1,}",r"\1",s)
'server_dev1_check_1233.zzz'
```

getting rid of the suffix is not the hardest part, just capture the rest and discard the end:

```
>>> re.sub(r"(.*_)\1{1,}(.*)(_\d+\..*)",r"\1\2",s)
'server_dev1_check'
```

Comment: hi thakns for the solution, i dont actually need the part from the number. i.e. _1233.zzz is not required. just `server_dev1_check`

Comment: just noticed. not the heart of the problem but okay:)